# Angular Submit Syntax and message if no results found using MovieDB API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm super new at web development and am trying to learn how to use Angular for a mini project.  I'm using The MovieDB's restful API's and all I want to do is a simple search for a movie title, return results that are found, and return a message if nothing is found.

Unfortunately I'm hitting a few comprehension hurdles and I have looked for a solution but haven't found one that matches what I'm doing, which I think is pretty simple (most of the ones I've seen are for more complex approaches and I think it's just beyond my understanding for the moment)

All I want to do right now is have a searchbar, a user types in a movie name, clicks submit, and the angular app will return results.  But I can't quite figure out how to pass the submit through to my app.  Here is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link
href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet" />
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="header">
    <img src="img\logo.png"
        style="width: 80px; height: 80px;&gt;
    &lt;div class="container">

    <h1>The MovieDB Search Tool</h1>
    <h2>Search for a movie!</h2>
</div>

<div class="main" ng-controller='MainController'>
    <div class="searchbar">
        <form ng-submit="submitFunction(field)">
            <input type="text" name="field" placeholder="Search for a       
             movie">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <div ng-repeat="details in movieList" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img ng-
               src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154{{details.poster_path}}">
                <p>{{ details.title }}</p>
                <p class="date">Release Date: {{ details.release_date | date 
                }}</p>
                <p>{{details.overview}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript code for the angular app:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 

$scope.movieTitle = function submitFunction(field){

}

$http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key='+api_key+'&language=en-US&query='
        +$scope.movieTitle+'&page=1&include_adult=false')
        .then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(response){
    $scope.movieList = response.data.results
}

function errorCallback(error){
}
}]);
```

If I plug in a movie name like 'Deadpool' the html works just fine, of course with a static value it runs automatically.  And I need it to work on submit, and the way I'm trying isn't working.  I would think I need to get a variable passed in to the $scope, buy the submit function but I'm not getting anything when I run this.

If I could get to this point, I think I could figure out the logic to display a message of no results found, it should be as simple as checking the json object the api returns and looking at the "total results" number, then returning a specific message (at least I hope it's that simple).

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are just starting out learning Angular, I'd highly recommend forgetting about Angularjs (Angular v1) and instead jump into the new version of Angular (Angular v2 or higher). It can be easier to use and comes with a code generator that helps you build apps quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submitFunction()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="movieTitle" placeholder="Search for a       
         movie">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 

$scope.submitFunction = function(){
    $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key='+api_key+'&language=en-US&query='+$scope.movieTitle+'&page=1&include_adult=false')
        .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
}



function successCallback(response){
    $scope.movieList = response.data.results
}

function errorCallback(error){
}
}]);
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!
It's always such a simple syntax, huge relief at the end of a long day!